# How to connect Dryer outlet to a power distribution unit?

Tags: electrical, 240v, adapter

I have a 240V (4-prong) dryer outlet. I want to buy PDU (power distribution unit) so that I connect the dryer outlet to PDU, then connect PDU to (non-server) power supplies. The power supplies are connected to computers that are used for Cryptocurrency mining.

edit: I don't have a dryer. The outlet will be dedicated to mining.

Comment: Dryer circuits are usually dedicated to and sized for one device. There's little overhead capacity built in. Is yours different somehow? Please revise to tell us more about the circuit, such as breaker and wire size.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of a properly protected temporary power distribution unit would significantly exceed that of installing a proper circuit.

Can it be done by code? Yes it can. (I have not looked into 2020 code as it is not yet adopted but believe the same requirements apply + the 240gfci).

I have built one for a young man that wanted the same thing in a rental house.
The 120v laundry circuit is dedicated.

I did not think this would be code compliant so I checked with one of my inspectors.

He reminded me that my portable power outlets used for building houses are basically the same thing.
They have breakers on the unit and each receptacle is GFCI protected. Everything connected to it is cord connected and not built in. So I built one based on 30 amps he was able to run 4 of his servers / OR the dryer. I believe we were on the 2014 code today that would require a GFCI on the dryer also even if the dryer is an older install without GFCI because this as a temporary install it could only be used for 90 days.  He stressed the 90 days and said who doesn't rearrange things every quarter anyway.
As a temporary installation for equipment that is cord connected it could be done but the cost was well over 3x that of an installed set of branch circuits.

I used a Hoffman box to house the 50a DPDT switch I used for the transfer and 5 receptacles inside the box was a small breaker panel fed on 1 side of the switch to the GFCI protected receptacles, the other side went to the dryer receptacle.

The only change I know of would be the requirement for the 240v receptacle to have GFCI protection but as a temporary setup I don’t see why it could not be done.  Note temporary is defined as 90 days and that would be the only way it would be legal.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a good idea. Here's where you're going to run into problems.

Your dryer outlet is two legs of 30A at 120v each with a common neutral and ground. GE says their electric dryers [take 22-25A](https://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-support-search-content?contentId=34592) (it's not clear if that's one circuit or both). So let's say you hook a 240v subpanel up to your existing 30A circuit (sanest way to do it). Then you hook your dryer and some number of mining machines up to that. When you turn your dryer on **you're heavily taxing that circuit**. Depending on the machine, some miners take a lot of amps to run. I found one mining machine that said it took 1350W, which is about 11A. 22 + 11 = 33 amps on your 30A circuit... Even if the dryer amps are split across both phases, you're still pushing it on what the circuit will carry, and if you overload one leg, both will trip.

So your options here are

1. Turn your mining machines off when you need to use the dryer
2. Run a separate circuit for your miners

I would highly recommend #2.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't have a dryer. that outlet will be dedicated to mining only.

Comment: I would subpanel it then. Turn that dual 30A circuits into some 20A circuits